# hola tengo este error en electron y react

Tags: reactjs, electron

Les muestro la configuración del `package.json` la versión de electrón que tengo es la 5 cuando ejecuto **yarn electron-pack** compila pero me sale este error:

```
"build" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

---

```
"pack": "electron-builder --dir",
"dist": "electron-builder"
```

y ejecutarlo con yarn dist

Comment: Saludos AN German, de casualidad ¿has visitado el link que te aparece en el error para ver la documentación?

Comment: Pero `yarn algo` no es la manera correcta de instalar desde un `package.json`, deberías usar `yarn install`. Como dice en el error, [revisa la documentación de yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install) para más información sobre cómo instalar paquetes.

Comment: Falta que nos muestres la sección de `scripts` de tu fichero `package.json`. Falta información de cómo pretendes hacer el empaquetado de la aplicación. ¿Usas alguna librería como [`electron-builder`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder)?. Si crees que puedes mejorar tu pregunta, te invito a hacer clic en [edit]. Saludos

Comment: @AlterLagos, creo que el OP no está intentando instalar sino ejecutar un `script` de su archivo `package.json`. Saludos

Comment: gracias a todos ya solucione este error era agregar con en scripts     "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"

Answer (score -1):

En el package.json añadí esto en los scripts:

```
"pack": "electron-builder --dir",
"dist": "electron-builder"
```

y ejecutarlo con

```
yarn dist
```